# nvidia-smi not working

Tags: cuda

In trying to install theano and cuda I am having problems verifying that it is installed properly.

I installed [cuda](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html) with

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

and rebooted, but when I run nvidia-smi I get

> nvidia-smi NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your
>   system. Please make sure that NVIDIA Display Driver is properly
>   installed and present in your system. Please also try adding directory
>   that contains libnvidia-ml.so to your system PATH.

I created a symlink

> ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi

and added to PATH

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates

but still have the error. Any ideas for a resolution?